# pyspark: parse text file with header and blank lines

Tags: pyspark

I am a newbie in pyspark.
I have a text file like below and I would like to parse it with pyspark and get only the abreviation of flowers as a list [ro,ni,da]. how can I do that ? please advise

## ---------

Plantes Abbreviations

Flowers:

ro rose

ni Nilofar

da Dahlia

## --------

Answer (score 0):

You load the file using textFile, then filter out the lines you don't want like below.  It is worth noting that you shouldn't assume any particular ordering to your text file because if it is large and split across multiple files or HDFS blocks you won't necessarily know where you are starting in it.

```
lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///some/path/to/plants.txt")

# Remove empty lines and header lines
abbrevs = lines.filter(lambda row: len(row) > 0) \
               .filter(lambda row: not row.startswith("Plantes")) \
               .filter(lambda row: not row.startswith("Flowers:")) \
               .map(lambda row: row.split())

only_abbrevs = abbrevs.map(lamdba row: row[0])

only_abbrevs.collect()
```

To transform any of the lines loaded, you can use map and provide a python lambda or function to change the data however you want.

Comment: Thanks! I want also the abbreviation in a list like [ro,ni,da]. How can I get this?

Comment: I added that to the example.